# MS Access forms with two subforms linked to the same table

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access Parent form, with two sub-forms (both linking to the same table)

I am trying to use the first subform as a navigation aid (in datasheet mode) and the other sub-form is used for data entry.

[image]

What Works:
- Currently I can add new person images easily from within subform1 and subform2 refreshes once I save the record.

What is not working
- Subform 2 is unbound to the person ID, so when I try to create a new record from within subform 2 the new record is not associated with the active person record.

Any Idea how this can be made to work better. (I am using a field on the main form (imageidLink) to link Subform2's master field.

Sample database can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwELxXjndunEOVRYd1lyZjcwSmM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the subform2 has [per_id] too:

Edit the default value property of `per_id` field in subform2, and put this expression:

```
=Forms![Person].form![per_id]
```

Then when you create a new record on subform2 it will be associated to active person record.